# parallelStream() causing ClassNotFoundException with JAXB-API

Tags: java, jaxb, classloader, java-11

In our application we sometimes get the following exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
```

We already found out that this happens only if we use `Collection.parallelStream()` but not if we use `Collection.stream()`.

We saw that JAXB uses `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` for loading classes. We also saw, that when using `parallelStream()`, the threads for executing our command are using different class loaders. Sometimes it's a `org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader`, and sometimes it's a `jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders.AppClassLoader`.

And it now seems, that the `AppClassLoader` does not know about the JAXB dependencies, whereas the `WebappClassLoader` does.

We are using Java 11 and the following Maven dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Any idea what could be wrong? How can it be, that the `AppClassLoader` does not know about our dependencies?

Answer (score 10):

We had a different experience.  The issue was that tomcat has a different classloader than each war (I think we're seeing something similar with spring boot apps; void-main was different than that of application-runner)..

Either way, the issue is that the "bootstrap" classloader doesn't have access to the jars in your application - and thus NO jaxb. So if you ever launch a thread (like `ForkJoinPoolThread` from `StreamXX.parallel()` or `ForkJoinPool.commonThreadPool()`) then THOSE threads will be from the bootstrap classloader, NOT your application's classloader.. So if the FIRST time your background task loads JAXB, they will run `getClass().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("xxxx")` and will not find the resource.

Our solution was to launch all background tasks in an explicit thread-pool and have an explicit thread-pool factory.. The thread-pool-factory captures the classloader from the invoking thread (the one initialized by the war or the spring-boot context). This classloader WILL have jaxb and friends.. So now each thread launched from this thread-pool factory has an explicit `thr.setContextClassLoader(globalCL);`....

Problem solved (via a hack)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue where I was getting ClassNotFoundException for `org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser`. I had removed/excluded dependencies for `xercesImpl`,`xml-api`,`xmlbeans`,`xmlschema-core` and the issue is resolved, though I have no idea why and how it worked. What prompted me to remove those jars was XMLReaderFactory which was present in `JDK 8` and `xml-api`.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading an older version of JAXB from somewhere. In Java 11 the context factory should be :
`com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory`

and not

```
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory
```

https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-api/issues/78

Try doing the following things:
upgrade your activation package to 1.2 . Not sure it has anything to do with it, but since you are using java 11 I would suggest using activation 1.2

Instead of plugging in glassfish implementation of jaxB. Use following dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**OR alternativly**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

If this still does not work fallback to the first thing I wrote you:

correct context factory is:

```
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory
```

There is an old vesion somewhere there loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The change in behavior was introduced in JDK9: [JDK-8184335 : Release Note: Fork/Join common pool threads return the system class loader as their thread context class loader](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8184335) (due to [JDK-8172726 : ForkJoin common pool retains a reference to the thread context class loader](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8172726)).

See also [Different classloaders in jdk8 and jdk11](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/19427).

Answer (score -1):

This class `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory` was previously available in the file `rt.jar` till `java 8`, and then was trimmed out from `jdk`.

---

**Possible cause:** Your application uses some library, which uses some old library, which expects `java 8`, which contains `xml.bind`, which is trimmed out from `jdk 11`.

---

**Workaround:** You can simply copy file `/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk/lib/rt.jar` from `jdk 8`, trim up a little its contents, saving only `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.*` packages. Then put this `jar` into your `tomcat/lib` folder.